# RecyclerView: How to load items only when the user has stopped scrolling?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

Currently, I'm developing a launcher app. The app has to load all icons into memory. In some older devices, when I load the app icons through the `PackageManager`, the app crashes. That's why I'm currently loading icons in the `onBindViewHolder(...)` method of `RecyclerView` in a background thread:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // ...

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
                    Drawable drawable = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(app.name.toString());

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        viewHolder.appIconIv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                });
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    // ...
}
```

But, the problem here is, the `RecyclerView` stutters/lags while scrolling even though the icons are being loaded in the background. Plus, if I scroll to the bottom, all the icons are loaded into memory causing the app to crash on older devices (with less RAM). Besides, I don't think this is a good solution as it has to create a new thread for every single **binding** of the views. So, my question is, whether it is possible to know if the user has stopped scrolling (and only load icons then).

> Any help regarding any of the issues I mentioned apart from the main question is **really really** appreciated and I'll be really grateful. [ specially all those performance/RAM issues :( ]

Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would heavily advise against ever using postAtFrontOfQueue for fear of pushing other things back. If you push things to the front, there's events that have the possibility of never getting executed resulting in strange behavior.

In an app I'm currently developing I'm waiting to load images with picasso until the user is done scrolling / flinging using this current implementation.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mPicasso.resumeTag(FeedViewHolder.SEARCH_IMAGE_TAG);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (Math.abs(dy) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
                mPicasso.pauseTag(FeedViewHolder.SEARCH_IMAGE_TAG);
            } else {
                mPicasso.resumeTag(FeedViewHolder.SEARCH_IMAGE_TAG);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can use picasso to load drawable resources and set the tag like this

```
mPicasso.load(R.drawable.image_resource_name)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .tag(SEARCH_IMAGE_TAG)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about `postAtFrontOfQueue`. I'll change that to just `post`.
Unfortunately, I don't think picasso supports loading drawables (from variables i.e already loaded drawable from the package manager, not sure though, correct me If I'm wrong). Besides, can you think of any other way, without using picasso? Thanks again for taking time :)

Comment: I would find some way to set each viewholder as a scroll listener on the recyclerview and then only load the image when they've stopped scrolling.

Maybe get a reference to the recyclerview in the adapter, when you create a new viewholder, add it as a scroll listener to the recyclerview since you can have multiple listeners. Then in each viewholder implement the scrolllistener interface and load the images on those callbacks.

Comment: I've tried your possible solution but the `OnScrollListener` is an abstract class, not an interface. Hence, I can't seem to find a way to implement those methods like you said.

Comment: You could create a concrete version of the class and in the constructor of your viewholder add it to the recyclerview. Just make sure every time you bind your viewholder, you set you need in order to have the scroll listener load the correct drawable when you stop scrolling.

Comment: But, I already extend the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class and for that reason, I can't create a concrete version of that class with the viewholder

Comment: value for SCROLL_THRESHOLD??

Answer (score 1):

from the Blog:[Image Loading with Picasso](https://nullpointer.wtf/android/image-loading-with-picasso/)

1. custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
2. Singleton Picasso
3. Picasso.pauseTag()

   RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PicassoOnScrollListener(this));

   Picasso.with(imageView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
           .load(url)
           .tag(PicassoOnScrollListener.TAG)
           .into(imageView);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm currently using Glide for my purpose :)